# PreparetoSegue Button Command to Another ViewController Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, prepare

How do I preparetoSegue a button command to another ViewController?  It seem my calculateButton is giving me an error code.

MainViewController

```
if (segue.identifier == "toCalculate") {

            let destViewController : CalcualteViewController = segue.destinationViewController as CalcualteViewController

            destViewController.calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {

                let dataone = data1.text.toInt() ?? 0

                let datatwo = data2.text.toInt() ?? 0

                let answercalculation = dataone * datatwo

                answer.text = "\(answercalculation)" + " psi"

            }
```

CalculateViewController

```
class CalcualteViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var answer: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var data1: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var data2: UITextField!

    @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destViewController.calculateButton` is a method of CalculateViewController. You have a closure hanging off the end of it when it doesn't accept any arguments accept `sender: AnyObject`. Move your logic into the `CalculateViewController`.

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
       let dataone = data1.text.toInt() ?? 0
       let datatwo = data2.text.toInt() ?? 0
       let answercalculation = dataone * datatwo
       answer.text = "\(answercalculation)" + " psi"
}
```

If you want to share the code across multiple controllers you could create an instance variable called `var calculateButtonAction: ((UIButton) -> ())?` and then set it in `prepareForSegue`:

```
destinationViewController.calculateButtonAction = { (sender) in
   let dataone = destinationViewController.data1.text.toInt() ?? 0
   let datatwo = destinationViewController.data2.text.toInt() ?? 0
   let answercalculation = dataone * datatwo
   destinationViewController.answer.text = "\(answercalculation)" + " psi"
}
```

And then call it from CalculatorViewController:

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
     if let action = calculateButtonAction {
        action(sender)
     }
}
```

Better yet, create a BaseCalculatorViewController and subclass it for your controllers so you can have your subclasses inherit `calculateButton`.

Comment: actually, I did originally set it up like you have mentioned before and have it working as is (on CalculateViewController, however, I wanted to preparedtosegue my button instead.

Comment: Reason being is I have 30 different calculation pages and didn't want to recreate 30 different ViewController.  I wanted the button command to be segue from the MainViewController instead.  I hope that make sense.

Comment: I'm having an error message with  destinationViewController.calculateButtonAction = { (sender) in ..... Cannot assign to 'calculateButtonAction in destViewController

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to wrap calculateButtonAction in an Optional. Try it with the revised code.

Comment: Hmmm...i'm still having issue with destinationViewController.calculateButtonAction = { (sender) in, error messageCalculateViewController does not have a member name 'calculateButtonAction

Comment: and issue with if let action = calculateButtonAction, unresolved identifier 'calculateButtonAction'

Comment: yes--you need to add `var calculateButtonAction: ((UIButton) -> ())?` as aproperty of any class that uses the calculateButtonAction

Comment: xcode recommended to change the code to destinationViewController.calculateButtonAction = { (sender as UIButton) in